# redirecting in php AFTER my page completes its functionality

Tags: php, redirect

I created a page that updates a database. I want that page to automatically send you back to the main page (the page that displays the database info)  after all of the code on the update page is done (and after a few seconds).

I put the header() function in but it seems to redirect before executing any code.  Is header the proper method to use?  Is there another way to redirect after the code and a short delay?

Comment: show us your code. All you have to do is put the header call after the updates AND before any output is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes but do it after you execute your code..

```
<?php
function foo(){
    //do stuff here

    header("Location: redirect.php");
    exit();
}
```

make sure you dont output anything else before you do the redirect or else it will show an error `headers already sent`

Comment: I actually find that I can put a text output, but the redirect occurs so fast that there is no time to read the message anyways, but it seems to work just fine with Firefox at least.  Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `header()` will do the job. Just call this code after your database update code:

```
header('Location: ...');
exit;
```

Why would you add any delay before redirecting?

Comment: so that there is time to see any error messages that pop up.  I have my code output " database successfully updated" if everything goes well, and errors if things dont go well.

Comment: Then an HTTP redirect is definitely not the solution you're after: either a meta refresh, or a javascript redirect, will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a header() redirect after executing PHP code. Make sure your header() call is after the code you want to run before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, use `header()` function with `Location: xxx`, just send it after your code complited activity. Also note, that in order for header() to take effect no real page output can be done before calling `header()` (although even that can be overcome by using output buffering).

Answer (score 0):

header() is the correct function to redirect, however header() function only works if there is no output to the page.

it would be nice if you can show some code here.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Comment: sorry about that, Im a novice coder (student) that is working for an educational institution (im working for a college as a student employee).  im supposed to be careful about code that I give out to 3rd party sites and such.  But like I said, im a novice so I need help from time to time to get everything working properly.  Thank you for the help by the way !!